# matplotlab How can I plot points in a loop using one array

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

This is a simplified example of a problem I am having.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    for i in range(0,10):
        plt.plot(i, i + 1)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

shows this. and

```
x = y = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(i + 1)
    plt.plot(x, y,)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

shows this.

How can I plot points in a loop so that I don't need to create two arrays?

Comment: When you do `plt.plot(i, i + 1)`, draws lines between 2 points, the code in the first loop only plots one point, therefore no line is drawn between the points and there are no markers on the points.

Comment: Run `for i in range(0,10): plt.plot([i, i+1], [i, i+1], marker='o')` as an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(0,10):
    plt.plot(i, i + 1, color='green', linestyle='solid', linewidth = 3, 
         marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass array as the first argumet to [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), this would plot y using x as index array 0..N-1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
plt.plot(range(10))

plt.show()
```

You'll find more interesting information at [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
max =10

for i in range(0,max):
    #scatter:
    #s=0 to make dissapeared the scatters
    ax.scatter(i, i + 1,s=1,facecolor='blue')
    #lines
    if i > 0:
        lc = LineCollection([[(i-1, i),(i, i+1)]])
        ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

result:
[image]